# Displaying number with commas while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a number with commas while typing itself. I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me out.

For example while typing 100000, it should automatically show 1,00,000 while typing itself. how can I do it?

Comment: use input mask check this http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: I tried using it, but it shows mask is not a function. This is what I've done.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="div1">
  <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1">
  <button type="button" id="button1">
 </div>
</body>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#input1").mask("99,99,999.99"); 
 });
</script>
</html>

Comment: @SaiKrishna You need to add this JS plugin to your page for this to work: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js

Comment: @nisar "1,2,3,4,5 6789" this is what I get as output. But, I should get 12,34,56,789.

Comment: @blex: I copied, pasted it and saved it as jquery. js and tried solving it. But, I got two errors, 1. jquery is not defined and $ is not defined. Since, I'm new to this I'm finding it difficult.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8e4kbxss/ .......only achieved by two text boxes...max tried...dont know @sai......

Comment: Thanks for your help @nisar.

Comment: @Rory ..is it duplicate ?...No....with a single text box,no one answered for thsi type of question.

Answer (score 0):

use angular..It makes very esay.
Try this one..
create directive..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.10" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" add-commas />
  </body>

</html>
```

js file

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {})
.directive('addCommas', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){

      el.bind('focus', function() {

        // remove the commas again at focus
        el.val(el.val().replace(/,/g , ""));
      });

      el.bind('keypress', function(e) {

        // Only allows one dot and two commas
        validate(e, this);
      });

      el.bind('blur', function(){

        // Add two decimal digits 
        var value = parseFloat(Math.round(el.val() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

        // Add 1000 seperator
        value = addCommas(value);

        // Update inputs value
        el.val(value);
      });

      function addCommas(nStr) {
        nStr += '';
        var x = nStr.split('.');
        var x1 = x[0];
        var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;
      }

      function validate(evt, ele) {
        var theEvent = evt || window.event;
        var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode( key );
        var value = ele.value + key;
        var regex = /^\d+(.\d{0,2})?$/;
        if( !regex.test(value) || key == ",") {
          theEvent.returnValue = false;
          if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wqnJd5jJchXdIfnb53iv?p=preview) may help you...

Comment: Thanks for your help @nisar. This is good but, my current learning process is on this(javascript and jQuery), so can you help  me with this in javascript and jQuery?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8e4kbxss/